# Взаимодействие с журналом звонков и телефонной книгой в Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Всем доброго времени суток.
Будьте так добры подскажите, каким
образом можно реализовать что-бы приложение получило доступ к журналу вызовов и телефонной книжке?
Точнее:
1) Могло считывать историю звонков
2) Вносить в журнал вызовов изменения если происходит звонок из приложения( отображалось как отображается Viber например )
3) Могло считывать информацию из телефонной книги и создавать новые контакты

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вам нужно использовать CallKit. Посмотрите уроки на эту тему в интернете.

Answer (score 1):

API для получения истории вызовов не является открытым, т.е. Вы не сможете опубликовать приложение в AppStore, которое использует вызовы закрытой части API. Такие фокусы обычно проворачивают на т.н. Jailbreak-устройствах.
Что же касается телефонной книги, то здесь Apple разрешает Вам очень многое. Для версии iOS 9 и новее есть специальные фреймворки `Contact` и `ContactUI` для работы со списком контактов. Приведу пример работы с `Contact`.

Прежде всего, добавьте в Ваш файл `Info.plist` строчку `NSContactsUsageDescription` для того, чтобы приложение могло работать с контактами.

Для создания нового контакта используйте следующий код (язык Swift 3.3):

```
func createContact() {

    //Прежде всего, надо получить от пользователя разрешение на использование контактной книги     
    let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts)
    //Если доступ к контактам запрещён, то новый контакт добавить не удастся
    if (status == CNAuthorizationStatus.denied || status == CNAuthorizationStatus.restricted) {

        return;
    }

    let store = CNContactStore()

    //Запросить разрешение у пользователя на доступ к контактам    
    store.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts) { (granted:Bool, error:Error?) in

        //Если пользователь отказался, то контакт добавить не удастся
        if (!granted) {

            return
        }

        let contact = CNMutableContact()
        contact.familyName = "Иванов"
        contact.givenName = "Иван"

        let homePhone = CNLabeledValue.init(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber.init(stringValue: "11-22-33"))
        contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone];

        let request = CNSaveRequest()
        request.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)

        do {

            try store.execute(request)
        } catch {

        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить список контактов используйте следующую функцию:

```
func getAllContacts() -> [CNContact] {

    let contacts: [CNContact] = {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let keysToFetch = [
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
            CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
            CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
            CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [Any]

        var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
        do {
            allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
        } catch {

        }

        var results: [CNContact] = []

        for container in allContainers {
            let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

            do {
                let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
                results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
            } catch {

            }
        }

        return results
    }()

    return contacts
}
```

Данную функцию Вы можете использовать к примеру следующим образом:

```
let allContacts = getAllContacts()
for contact in allContacts {

    print("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)")
}
```